# How do I save a report to a new location every time I run a testrunner script in CLI - SOAPUI

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface, soapui, test-runner

I am running a script through `testrunner` CLI through a Jenkins build. I want the result's saved to a new folder for each run. How do i do it?

> testrunner.bat -r -j -J "-fC:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\Reports\xxx\xxx" "-RProject Report" "-EDefault environment" -I "C:\TCOE\Automated_Smoke_and_Regression_SoapUI_Tests\xxx\xxx_PRODUCTION-soapui-project.xml"

Right now the script looks like the above pasted one. Where I declare the root location for the report explicitly.

What do I do to ensure each run saves the report in a new location?

Do I do it through Jenkins or SOAPUI? What is the best approach?

Thanks
Sandip

Comment: Are you using Ready API? Do you use junit style reports? Is reports overwrite each time currently? Please update the question with these information.

Comment: Are you using Ready API?  - Yes;   

Do you use junit style reports? - Yes;   

Is reports overwrite each time currently? - Yes they do. So, you understand my predicament. I want to save each & every report.;

Comment: How are you calling the above command (mentioned the question) in jenkins? By the way thanks for your previous answers. And what kind of job you configured in jenkins?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Ans: By adding a build (windows batch) step and adding the above command in it. I thought it'll be easier to schedule than trying to do it in a desktop batch script. I'm finding my way through Jenkins & trying to refind my way with SOAPUI.

Please help!

Comment: If you want to wrap that command into a batch file, then it would be easy to assign a new directory name each time based on date. You can give it a shot, then you can directly call that script in jenkins as well if you want.

Comment: Are you suggesting making it into a service?
Could you please elaborate?
Thank you for response.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question?

Through CLI how do I ensure Reports aren't overwritten and saved to a new location for every subsequent run?

Comment: Sandip, have you got chance to try the solution provided in the answer?

Comment: Hi Rao,I'm going to try it now. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is windows batch file which would allow you set the dynamic directory using `date time` for the result to be captured without over writing the previous results.

Of course, you may call batch file from Jeninks as well.

copy the below script to a file say, `wrapper_testrunner.cmd` and place this file where testrunner.bat is located. Because it is call soapui's `testrunner.bat` file, i.e., place this batch file under `SOAPUI_HOME/bin` directory.

```
@echo off

REM Provide the base directory where the results needs to be saved
REM A new dynamic directory is created using date time under this directory
set RESULTS_BASE_DIR=C:\Temp\TEST_Results

REM Set the soapui project to run 
set PROJECT=C:\Temp\Project\hellow-world-soapui-project.xml

REM Set the environment name
set ENVIRONMENT_NAME="Default environment"

REM set the dynamic directory name using date time
set mdate=%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%


REM create dynamic directory for results
mkdir %RESULTS_BASE_DIR%\%mdate%

REM run the project using testrunner
call testrunner.bat -f %RESULTS_BASE_DIR%\%mdate% -E %ENVIRONMENT_NAME% -raj %PROJECT%
```

If you needed to change any value of the variable, feel free to change, I just put the place holders only.

Having said, that you also add any additional options required to be passed to `testrunner.bat` file.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: @SandipDas, appreciate you can upvote & accept it as answer then. And glad to know that it is helpful.