# How to run multiple projects in SOAP UI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have around 30 projects in SOAP UI, i need to run all the projects in one go.

could anyone help me to implement this or is there any framework or add in to implement this.

Comment: Why do you want to run in soapui, possible to get hanged. Instead use command line testruner utility.

Comment: I think you probably want something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512075/how-do-i-save-a-report-to-a-new-location-every-time-i-run-a-testrunner-script-in/40530155#40530155

Comment: There are too many possible answers. What OS? Are you using any CI? Will this be from CLI by one single user?